# Change a class of T to another T

Tags: c#, generics

how would i convert the T to another T without having to implement IConvertable interface.

i want to change the T of the class which used to be an int to a double, i'm not sure how to do this through reflection

```
public class TestClass<T>
{
    private T value_;
    public TestClass(T val)
    {
        value_ = val;
    }


    public T Compute()
    {
        return value_;
    }
}


 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var tClass = new TestClass<int>(5);
        var value = tClass.Compute();
        //now make compute return a double without doing a (double)tClass.Compute()
        //i want to change the T of the class which used to be an int to a double, i'm not sure how to do this through reflection
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Once you have instanced an object `TClass<T>` with `int` you cannot change it, You can create a new one, `var tClassDouble = new TestClass<double>(5d);`

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense without context - as it stands, the answer is "stop using generics."

Comment: This sounds very much like an XY problem, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Agree with everyone. Missing more context. One solution is for you to change the return type of Compute to double. You deal with the conversion inside the code of Compute.